# Calculate total of row and total of all rows in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have invoice rows which can be added and deleted by pressing on a button. Now i want to **calculate the total amount for each row** separately(for which the formula is (quantity * unitprice) * vat_percentage). **And the total of all rows combined should become the total of the invoice.**

**I have this RoR form:**

```
 <%= f.fields_for :products do |product| %>
 <tbody>
   <tr class="products_tr">
     <td> <%= product.text_field :quantity, class: 'quantity form-control' %> </td>
     <td> <%= product.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %> </td>
     <td> <%= product.text_field :unitprice, class: 'unitprice form-control' %> </td>
     <td class='total' readonly="readonly"> 100 </td>
     <td> <%= product.select(:vat, [[' 21%', 21, title: '21%'],[' 6%', 6, title: '6%'], [' 0%', 0, title: '0%']], class: 'vat_percentage') %> </td>
     <td class='delete_tr'><a class="delete" title="delete row"><span class="ti-close"></span></a></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
 </tbody>
```

**The code for adding rows:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = $('.products_tr').length;
    $('#add_products').click(function() {
      $('.products_tr:last').after('<tr class="products_tr"><td><input class="quantity form-control" type="text" value="" name="invoice[products_attributes]['+counter+'][quantity]"></td>' +
          '<td><textarea class="form-control" name="invoice[products_attributes]['+counter+'][description]"></textarea></td>' +
          '<td><input id="unitprice" class="unitprice form-control" type="text" name="invoice[products_attributes]['+counter+'][unitprice]"></td>' +
          '<td class="total" readonly="readonly"> 100 </td>' +
          '<td><select name="invoice[products_attributes]['+counter+'][btw]"><option title="21%" value="21"> 21%</option> ' +
          '<option title="6%" value="6"> 6%</option><option title="0%" value="0"> 0%</option></select></td>' +
          '<td class="delete_tr"><a class="delete" title="Rij verwijderen"><span class="ti-close"></span></a></td></tr>');
      counter ++;
    });
  });
```

**I have this code for calculating the total of the row (showing NaN)**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;
    var quantity       =  parseInt($('.quantity').val());
    var unitprice      =  parseFloat($('.unitprice').val());
    var vat_percentage =  parseFloat($('.vat_percentage').val());
    total              =  (quantity * unitprice) * vat_percentage;

    $('.total').closest('.total').text(total);
  });
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How do you calculate the total for each row since they all have the same class and how do you add all the row totals together.

Comment: you probably want to use an $.each() iterator over your class and within each iteration, add to the total value for each variable, then after the loop, perform your total summary logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just a real quick, might be this will be helpfull

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var total = 0,rowtotal=0;;
       $('.products_tr').each(function(){  
        var quantity       =  parseInt($(this).find('.quantity').val());
        var unitprice      =  parseFloat($(this).find('.unitprice').val());
        var vat_percentage =  parseFloat($(this).find('.vat_percentage').val());
        rowtotal              =  (quantity * unitprice) * vat_percentage;
        $(this).find('.total').text(rowtotal);
        total+=rowtotal;
       })
    });
```

Comment: This wasn't completely the right answer but it helped me get on the right track

Answer (score 1):

Use the `each` function to go over each element with the `products_tr` class. For each row you can use jquery to get the number you want and parse it or set it.

```
var total=0;
$('.products_tr').each(function(){
    var quantity=parseInt($('.quantity',this).text());
    var unit=parseFloat($('.unitprice',this).text());
    var vat=parseFloat($('.vat_percentage',this).text());
    var row=quantity*unit*vat;
    $('.total',this).text(row);
    total+=row;
});
```

Comment: I tested it with a random table of values and it worked, where/when did you use it?

Comment: I used it on the form i added in the original post. And i tried all kinds of variations even with .on() and removing the vat_percentage but it still shows NaN/